# Command du -xh / | grep -P "G\t" explained?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression, options

I came across the command

```bsh
du -xh / | grep -P "G\t"
```

I am interested in the switch `-P` of `grep` and what does it do. Also, can anyone explain what the `"G\t"` part does?

Please do not explain `du -xh` or the basics of the command `grep`.

```bsh
$ du -xh / | grep -P "G\t"
5.1G    /var/oracle/XE/datafile
5.1G    /var/oracle/XE
5.1G    /var/oracle
1.1G    /var/lib
6.9G    /var
1.9G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/install/fix
1.9G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/install
1.2G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/Designer
1.3G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/common
1.9G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/CCE
1.2G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer/instances/default/replicate/salvage
3.0G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer/instances/default/replicate
2.3G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer/instances/default/packages
5.5G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer/instances/default
5.5G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer/instances
5.7G    /opt/softwareag/webMethods/IntegrationServer
16G     /opt/softwareag/webMethods
16G     /opt/softwareag
16G     /opt
1.1G    /usr/share
3.0G    /usr
11G     /u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE
11G     /u01/app/oracle/oradata
12G     /u01/app/oracle
12G     /u01/app
12G     /u01
39G     /
```

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I was tempted to do so, because of the way you dismissively say that you don’t need to have the “basics of command `grep`” explained to you, but you show no signs of having tried to research your question.  Did you read ```man grep```?  Did you try running the `du` command with and without the `grep` filter and look for differences?  If you had done those things, and *said so* in the question, and identified the part(s) that you didn’t understand, it probably wouldn’t have been downvoted.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … You say “No question that is asked is bad.” Stack Exchange disagrees with you; we believe that there certainly is such a thing as a bad question.

Comment: I feel cheated: reading a complex command (pipe-line), then being told to ignore most of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the `grep` manual, `-P` enables the use of PCREs, i.e. Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.

The PCRE expression `G\t` matches a `G` followed by a tab.

The effect is that you only get a listing of directories whose size is listed in gigabytes (or whose name happens to match the pattern).

An alternative pipeline that would more reliable match the `G` at the end of the first tab-delimited column only:

```
... | awk -F '\t' '$1 ~ /G$/'
```

Would you also want to see the entries that are shown in units smaller or larger than gigabytes, then change `G` into `[KMGTPEZY]`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i understand now. I saw from man pages , but could not understand until u explained. And i dont know why guys are giving bad points for post, when this is website for helping others. If i m less cleaver then you, and dont understand it alone, its not reason to give minus points for post. No question that is asked is bad.

Comment: @MilošStojanović Sorry, but I did not downvote your question. That must have been somebody else. People downvote questions for all sorts of reasons, ranging from bad grammar or unreadable text to leaving out information.

Comment: I m just wondering. Can u help and give me advice how to make new lines when i type the post? because everything is staying at the same line. And only ```` trick i know ```` but that cant be used for simple text,because i got correction already by some people for using it for simple text.

Comment: @Milo you can use the formatting sandbox (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/270345) to test formatting and https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help to learn the syntax

Comment: And it would be consistent with the spirit and intent of the command to replace the ``G`` with ``[GTPEZY]``, to match gigabytes, terabytes, or larger.

Answer (score 1):

`-P` enables Perl-compatible regex engine, which isn't the default one. In your example it is required to make `\t` treated as a tab symbol.

Otherwise `grep` will consider it as a plain `t` (escaped with `\`).

P.S. You could easily figure this out based on the man page:

> #### OPTIONS
>
>   <...>
>   **Matcher Selection**
>   <...>
>   **`-P`**
>   ,
>   **`--perl-regexp`**
>     Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE). 
>     This is experimental and
>     **`grep -P`**
>     may warn of unimplemented features.