# I'm trying to understand how to shorten regex

Tags: linux, bash, grep, regular-expression, disk-usage

I'm trying to list all directories that are 1GB or larger. I know I could use `ncdu`, but at the moment, I'm just trying to understand how to shorten regex...

I found this command, `du -h . | grep '[0-9\.]\+G'` but I don't understand how it works.

I tried to write it the way I know regex, and this is what I came up with:
`du -h . | grep '[0-9]\+\.*[0-9]*G`

I think the first command looks for 0 through 9 and a period afterwards, the `\+` indicates one or more; so I think all results that *don't have dots* should be excluded, but they are not.

Shouldn't the first command be something like this?
`grep '[0-9\.]*G'`

Thank you.

Comment: `[0-9]\+\.*[0-9]*G` matches somerhing like `4+.....7777777G` ... the `+` and the `.` are literal because they are preceeded by the escape character \

Comment: @jsotola `+` and `.` are not literal. the command works fine. I tested it. I'm only trying to understand why the short command is skipping so many steps.

Comment: "I think the first command looks for 0 through 9 and a period afterwards" `[0-9.]` (or, equivalently, `[.0-9]`, `[0123456789.]`, `[01.2-9]`, etc.) is any of the characters between 0 and 9 inclusive or the character `.`.

Comment: You have about three questions in there. What is the central question that you want people to answer? I'm also aware of a similar question that may or may not be a duplicate of this: [Command du -xh / | grep -P "G\t" explained?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/525605)

Comment: @jsotola To my knowledge, the meaning of `\+` is undefined in basic regular expressions. GNU implementations interpret this as "one or more occurences", while others take undefined backslash combinations like if there was no backslash, thus a literal `+` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @muru 
-- Philippos, do you mean like when grep regex is different from ack regex? I normally use ack because it uses regex that's simple to understand without multiple escaping requirements.

Comment: I mean there is a POSIX definition of RE which does not specify what to do with most backslash combinations, one of those being `\+`. The GNU implementation does take this as shortcut for `\{1,\}`, while others take it as literal `+`. Most linux tool will normally use the GNU interpretation, but if you don't know, you should not rely on that. You see that jstola gets different results from yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `[...]` is a bracket group, it matches a single character that's any of the ones listed inside, obeying ranges (in some way that depends on the locale). `[0-9\.]` matches any digit from zero to nine, the backslash or the dot. They've probably added the backslash there since they think the dot needs to be escaped, but that's not the case inside a bracket group.

In standard basic regular expressions (BRE), `\+` is undefined, so the regex is actually invalid. In GNU systems, it works like the `+` from extended regular expressions (ERE) and matches one or more of the previous. In other systems, it might do something else. The `G` just matches a literal `G`.

There's no reason to use the GNU-specific expression here, as we could just rewrite it to standard ERE and tell grep to use that instead of BRE. That could be

```
grep -E '[0-9.]+G'
```

which would match at least one digit or dot, followed by a G.

> I think the first command looks for 0 through 9 and a period afterwards

No, there's no order inside a bracket expression. `[xyz.]` is the same as `[z.yx]`. If it was `[0-9]\.`, then it would look for any single digit followed by a single dot. (Here, the dot needs to be escaped.)

> Shouldn't the first command be something like this? `grep '[0-9\.]*G'`

That would make the digit (or dot) optional, and would match any line with a `G`. Actually, the "one or more" in the original is unnecessary too; since the expression isn't anchored to anything at the beginning, `[0-9.]G` would also implicitly accept any number of digits (or dots). (i.e. in `123G` it would match just `3G` and grep would still print the whole line.)

<sub>(`[0-9]` can match more characters than just `0123456789`, it depends on the locale's sort order if there other characters that sort along the digits.)</sub>

---

Note that with the output of `du` containing the directory size and the name, grep would also match any lines that have e.g. `1G` in the pathname. Also if `du` can print the sizes in terabytes etc., it'd miss lines that have a size like `1.2T` or so. To avoid that, you'd need to anchor the expression to the start of the line and add at least the `T`:

```
du -h . | grep -E '^[0-9.]+[GT]'
```

(This needs the `+`, since `^[0-9.][GT]` would just look for a single digit (or dot) between the start of the line and the `G` or `T`. I.e. it'd find `1G`, but not `1.2G`.)

Or use e.g. awk:

```
du -h . | awk '$1 ~ /[GT]/'
```

(No need to look for the digits, really. We know they're there.)